# Filter Elasticsearch Aggregation by Bucket Key Value

Tags: elasticsearch, key-value, aggregation, bucket

I have an Elasticsearch index of documents in which there is a field that contains a list of URLs. Aggregating on this field gives me the count of unique URLs, as expected.

```
GET models*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then want to filter out the buckets whose keys do not contain a certain string. I've tried doing so with the [Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html).

This attempt:

```
GET models*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "links_key_filter": {
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "key": "links"
        },
        "script": "!key.contains('foo')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fails with:

> Invalid pipeline aggregation named [links_key_filter] of type
>   [bucket_selector]. Only sibling pipeline aggregations are allowed at
>   the top level

Putting the bucket selector inside the links aggregation, like so:

```
GET models*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "key": "links"
        },
        "script": "!key.contains('foo')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

fails with:

> Found two aggregation type definitions in [links]: [terms] and [bucket_selector]

I'm going to keep tinkering but am a bit stuck at the moment :(

Comment: I think in the second case you're missing the `aggs` section in which the `links_key_filter ` aggregation should go

Comment: were you able to figure it out? how did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

You **won't** be able to use the `bucket_selector` because its `bucket_path`

> must reference either a number value or a single value numeric metric aggregation [[source]](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/d181b947c265fcca9798c5e80eeeda15df5e2d27/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/pipeline/BucketHelpers.java#L152)

and what a `terms` aggregation produces is denoted as `StringTerms` — and that simply won't work, regardless of whether you [force a placeholder multibucket aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66294856/8160318) or not.

#### Having said that, each `terms` aggregation supports the [`exclude` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4).

Assuming that your links are arrays of keywords:

```json
POST models/_doc/1
{
  "links": [
    "google.com",
    "wikipedia.org"
  ]
}

POST models/_doc/2
{
  "links": [
    "reddit.com",
    "google.com"
  ]
}
```

and you'd like to group everything except `reddit`, you can use the following regex:

```json
POST models*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links.keyword",
        "exclude": ".*reddit.*",    <-- 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, There are some non-trivial implications arising from the usage of such regexes, esp. when you imagine a case-sensitive scenario in which you'd need a query-time-generated regex — as discussed in [How to correctly query inside of terms aggregate values in elasticsearch, using include and regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581838/how-to-correctly-query-inside-of-terms-aggregate-values-in-elasticsearch-using-include-and-regex)

Answer (score -2):

```
GET models*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }

    },
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "key": "links"
        },
        "script": "!key.contains('foo')"
      }
  }
}
```

> Your selector should come a level up, it should be directly in the aggs and parallel to your selector group. 
>   I am not sure about the key filtering

Answer (score -2):

You can use "_key" to get keys:

```
GET models*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "links.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "key": "_key"
        },
        "script": "!params.key.contains('foo')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```