# Elasticsearch return unique string from array field after a given filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How would I get all values of all the ids with a given prefix from the elastic search records and make them unique.

**Records**

```
PUT items/1
{ "ids" :  [ "apple_A", "orange_B" ] }

PUT items/2
{ "ids" :  [ "apple_A", "apple_B" ] }

PUT items/3
{ "ids" :  [ "apple_C", "banana_A" ] }
```

What I need is to find all the unique ids for a given prefix, for example if input is apple the output of ids should be  `["apple_A", "apple_B", "apple_C"]`

What I have tried so far is make use of the term aggregation, with the following query I was able to filter out the documents which have ids with given prefix but in the aggregation it will return all the ids part of the document.

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "filterIds": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "prefix": {
                "ids.keyword": {
                  "value": "apple"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "uniqueIds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ids.keyword",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's returning aggregation list as [ "appleA", "orange_B", "apple_B","apple_C", "banana_A"] if we give prefix input as apple. Basically returning all ids which have a matching filter.

Is there to get only the ids which match the prefix in array and not all the ids in the array of document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the returned values using the [`include` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4):

```
POST items/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "filterIds": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "prefix": {
                "ids.keyword": {
                  "value": "apple"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "uniqueIds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ids.keyword",
            "include": "apple.*"    <--
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do check [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65581838/8160318) which deals with using regex within `include` -- it's very similar to your use case.