# How can I get auto-suggestions for synonyms match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

I'm using the code below and it does not give auto-suggestion as **curd** when i type **"cu"**

But it does match the document with yogurt which is correct.
How can I get both auto-complete for synonym words and document match for the same?

```json
PUT products
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
            "lowercase",
              "synonym_graph"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym_graph": {
            "type": "synonym_graph",
            "synonyms": [
               "yogurt, curd, dahi"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
PUT products/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "description": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
POST products/_doc
{
  "description": "yogurt"
}
```

```json
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": "cu"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide a list of synonyms in a `synonym_graph` filter it simply means that ES will treat any of the synonyms interchangeably. But when they're analyzed via the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), only **full-word tokens** [will be produced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

```json
POST products/_analyze?filter_path=tokens.token
{
  "text": "yogurt",
  "field": "description"
}
```

yielding:

```json
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "curd"
    },
    {
      "token" : "dahi"
    },
    {
      "token" : "yogurt"
    }
  ]
}
```

As such, a regular `match_query` won't cut it here because the standard analyzer hasn't provided it with enough context in terms of matchable substrings ([n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)).

In the meantime you can replace `match` with **[`match_phrase_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)** which does exactly what you're after -- match an ordered sequence of characters while taking into account the synonyms:

```json
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "description": "cu"
    }
  }
}
```

But that, as the query name suggests, is only going to work for prefixes. If you fancy an autocomplete that suggests terms **regardless of where the substring matches occur**, have a look at my other answer where I [talk about leveraging n-grams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584264/8160318).

Comment: Thanks @Joe for looking into this. I am using the same query above and it matches the right document but I dont get **curd** in the autosuggest as it is the synonym but I get match for **yogurt**. I wanted even the suggestion as **curd**. Currently, I dont get any suggestion except yogurt. Please can you let me know how I can achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The thing is, it only works in one direction -- i.e. you search for curd and get yogurt back because the two are said to be synonyms. Having said that, you'll only receive the actual document that you stored in ES -- i.e. the one with yogurt. ES cannot magically return documents (or document "alternatives" that doesn't store. Hope that makes sense. So your best bet is to have a hashmap of synonyms where you post-process the ES response and enrich the results with synonyms before they're passed to a frontend autocomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So, I'm using autocomplete library for suggestions then passing it to ES. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome @jason! Hey btw -- my handbook containing actionable elasticsearch guides is coming very soon! You can [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) which topics interest you the most and I'll let you know when it's out.

Comment: Nice Joe! These topics - Implementation of End to End application as search and sub-modules like Knowledge Graph implementation and unfolding and ranking and recommendations. Also above $150 is fine. Also, exception case handling with intent detection.

Comment: Cool! Would you mind filling out [the typeform](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) (also shared above)? I wouldn't want you to paste your email here :)

Comment: Done! You can probably have a website like https://www.educative.io where you can keep updating courses instead of 1 book. You can cover more topics in depth and we can access it from anywhere. I guess this might help everyone! All the best. Let me know when it is out!

Comment: Thanks for signing up & for the tip!

Comment: My Pleasure! How can I reach out to you? Is there any stackoverflow messenger or chat?

Comment: You can reach me at joe@elasticsearchbook.com!

Comment: Cool! Thanks Joe!