# How to get per term statistics in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to implement the following (on the backend): a user types a query and gets back hits as well as statistics for the hits. Below is a simplified example.

Suppose the query is `Grif`, then the user gets back (random words just for example)

- Griffith
- Griffin
- Grif
- Grift
- Griffins

And frequency + number of documents a certain term occurs in, for example:

- Griffith (freq 10, 3 docs)
- Griffin (freq 17, 9 docs)
- Grif (freq 6, 3 docs)
- Grift (freq 9, 5 docs)
- Griffins (freq 11, 4 docs)

I'm relatively new to Elasticsearch, so I'm not sure where to start to implement something like this. What type of query is the most suitable for this? What can I use to get that kind of statistics? Any other advice will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple layers to this. You'd need:

- [n-gram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) / partial / search-as-you-type matching
- a way to group the matched keywords by their original form
- a mechanism to reversely look up the document & term frequencies.

#### I'm not aware of any way to achieve this in **one** go, but here's my take on it.

1. You could start off with a special, n-gram-powered analyzer, as explained [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584264/8160318). There's the original `content` field, plus a [multi-field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) for the said analyzer, plus a `keyword` field to aggregate on down the line:

```json
PUT my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "max_ngram_diff": 20
    },
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngrams": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngrams_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngrams",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "analyzed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_ngrams_analyzer"
          },
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Next, bulk-insert some sample docs containing text inside the `content` field. Note that each doc has an `_id` too — you'll need those later on.

```json
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":1}}
{"content":"Griffith"}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":2}}
{"content":"Griffin"}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":3}}
{"content":"Grif"}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":4}}
{"content":"Grift"}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":5}}
{"content":"Griffins"}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":6}}
{"content":"Griffith"}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index", "_id":7}}
{"content":"Griffins"}
```

3. Search for n-grams in the `.analyzed` field and group the matched documents by the original terms through the [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). At the same time, retrieve the `_id` of one of the bucketed documents through the [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html). BTW — it doesn't matter which `_id` is returned in a given bucket — all will have contained the same bucketed term.

```json
POST my-index/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.buckets.doc_count,aggregations.*.buckets.*.hits.hits._id
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "content.analyzed": "grif"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "full_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "content.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_doc": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. Observe the response. The `filter_path` URL parameter from the previous request reduces the response to just those attributes that we need — the untouched, original `full_terms` plus *one* of the underlying IDs:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "full_terms" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Griffins",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "top_doc" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_id" : "5"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Griffith",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "top_doc" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_id" : "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Grif",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "top_doc" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_id" : "3"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Griffin",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "top_doc" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_id" : "2"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Grift",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "top_doc" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_id" : "4"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### Time for the fun part.

There's a specialized Elasticsearch API called [Term Vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) which does ***exactly*** what you're after — it retrieves field & term stats from the whole index. In order for it to hand these stats over to you, it needs the document IDs — which you'll have obtained from the above aggregation!

5. Finally, since you've got multiple term vectors to work with, you can use the [Multi term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-multi-termvectors.html#docs-multi-termvectors-api-example) like so — again condensing the response thru `filter_path`:

```json
POST /my-index/_mtermvectors?filter_path=docs.term_vectors.*.*.*.doc_freq,docs.term_vectors.*.*.*.term_freq
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "5",                 <--- guaranteeing
      "fields": [
        "content.keyword"
      ],
      "payloads": false,
      "positions": false,
      "offsets": false,
      "field_statistics": false,
      "term_statistics": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "1",                 <--- the response
      "fields": [
        "content.keyword"
      ],
      "payloads": false,
      "positions": false,
      "offsets": false,
      "field_statistics": false,
      "term_statistics": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "3",                 <--- order
      "fields": [
        "content.keyword"
      ],
      "payloads": false,
      "positions": false,
      "offsets": false,
      "field_statistics": false,
      "term_statistics": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "fields": [
        "content.keyword"
      ],
      "payloads": false,
      "positions": false,
      "offsets": false,
      "field_statistics": false,
      "term_statistics": true
    },
    {
      "_id": "4",
      "fields": [
        "content.keyword"
      ],
      "payloads": false,
      "positions": false,
      "offsets": false,
      "field_statistics": false,
      "term_statistics": true
    }
  ]
}
```

6. The result can be post-processed in your backend to form your autocomplete response. You've got A) the full terms, B) the number of matching documents (`doc_freq`), and C), the term frequency:

```json
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "term_vectors" : {
        "content.keyword" : {
          "terms" : {
            "Griffins" : {      |      term
              "doc_freq" : 2,   | <--  # of docs
              "term_freq" : 1   |      term frequency
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term_vectors" : {
        "content.keyword" : {
          "terms" : {
            "Griffith" : {
              "doc_freq" : 2,
              "term_freq" : 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term_vectors" : {
        "content.keyword" : {
          "terms" : {
            "Grif" : {
              "doc_freq" : 1,
              "term_freq" : 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term_vectors" : {
        "content.keyword" : {
          "terms" : {
            "Griffin" : {
              "doc_freq" : 1,
              "term_freq" : 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "term_vectors" : {
        "content.keyword" : {
          "terms" : {
            "Grift" : {
              "doc_freq" : 1,
              "term_freq" : 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Shameless plug: if you're new to Elasticsearch and, just like me, learn best from real-world examples, consider buying [my Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com).

Comment: What if my `content` field needs to be really big? Is it possible? What are the caveats?

Comment: ES returns `Document contains at least one immense term in field="content.keyword" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms. The prefix of the first immense term is: '..', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 103339` if I try to index `content` of size ~100k characters.

Comment: `.keyword` fields are not designed for such large strings. You could try splitting the content into `content_N`, `content_N+1` etc...

Comment: So, there's no other ways, only to split into separate fields like `content_part_1`, `content_part_2`... `content_part_N` ?

Comment: To be frank, my answer was rather intended for short, keyword-like strings, not super long text fields. The above approach takes advantage of the fact that you can quickly **aggregate** on the keywords and thus get the most represented ones returned. You can do **without** this aggregation (and without the whole `keyword` mapping) to get rid of this error but will then need some other way to extract the user-defined query matches out of the long text fields -- maybe through [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html).

Comment: I had been thinking about highlighting before I asked this question. Should I like fuzzy search through the content field, extract matched terms.. How do I get the statistics this way? I mean, it ES will return  the `highlight` object like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/1sbE0jVu) and the hits. I don't get how to establish "relations" between hits and highlighted terms

Comment: Use the Multi Terms Vector API as I did in the 2nd part of my answer. You'll need two requests -- one for the highligting, one for the term vectors. If both are fast enough, the end user won't notice.

Comment: OK. Just want to be sure I understood everything correctly:
1) I make a search request with highlight feature & get hits
2) Make a Multi Terms Vector request for document ids taken from hits
3) Filter response of (2) using highlighted terms from (1)

Comment: Yup, you got it.